# How can I delete files named by numbers?

Tags: bash, wildcard, delete-file

I have 200 files on a linux machine, each one's name is 100, 101, 102, 103 etc... I'd like to delete 100-150, how can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have 200 files, each one's name is 100, 101, 102, 103 etc... I'd
>   like to delete 100-150

You can say:

```
rm {100..150}
```

or

```
rm -f {100..150}     # -f would ignore nonexistent files, never prompt
```

Comment: I'm sorry, my details were incorrect, the files names are 100.file 101.file etc...

Comment: @ItaiGanot Say `rm -f {100..150}.file` in that event.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete those by using range: 
rm -f {100..150}